# Validate comma delimited input without allow spaces

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a validation pattern for an input which should accept only a list of words [a-z0-9] delimited by commas. Commas could be spaced with spaces or not.

Example:

```
OK   foo,bar
OK   foo, bar
OK   foo , bar
NO   foo, bar,
NO   foo , bar ,
NO   fo o, bar
```

This is my current solution:

```
^[a-z0-9]+(?:,[a-z0-9]*)*$
```

But it lacks support for spaced commas and it allows a trailing comma (which should not be allowed).
How can I fix my regex?

Comment: What about `" foo,bar "` or `" foo "` (leading/trailing spaces or single items)?

Comment: no problem with them, I just remove every space server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following pattern:

```
^[a-z\d]+(?:\s*,\s*[a-z\d]+)*$
```

with the ignorecase flag (`i`)